# What could be the reason that GWT-mobile apps doesnt really work on mobile device?

Tags: gwt, mobile

what could be the reason for that, that gwt mobile apps doesnt really work on mobile phone?
iam using a ZTE-Blade Android 2.1 (in germany Base Lutea) mobile phone and i have big problems with gwt-mobile-apps while using this mobile phone.
the gwt-apps are running but there is no reaction when i touch UI like buttons or something.

i must press the button maybe over 100 times to get a reaction.
and that is the case for every gwt mobile app.

Nearly no reaction from UIs like buttons for every gwt-mobile-app.
I wrote a little app in gwt and on the browser on my PC, it works perfect but on my mobile not really.

with other apps like android or jquery-apps, there are no problems.
everything works fine but with gwt-mobile-apps there are no reactions by touching UIs like buttons.

What could be the reason for that?
i really have no idea.
does somebody know this problem and are there similar problems for gwt-mobile-apps on other devices?

Comment: Do you have a link where we can test it?

Comment: http://de.appbrain.com/app/gwt-mobile-ui/com.gwtmobile.ui.kitchensink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem on my 2.1 android phone and the only problem is that android 2.1 is to old.
gwtmobile works very nice on younger android devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you look when the developers made the last updates to this framework it shows that they haven't updated it since April 2010.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/

Because of the deversity of mobile devices and browsers it hard to optimze javascript for every type of browser.

You should use a framework which is up to date like jQuery mobile or Sencha Touch 2. They are well focused on this topic.

http://jquerymobile.com/

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Statement of sencha:
"A note about Android support: Due to the overwhelming diversity of physical Android devices on the market, we can only test so many. This support matrix is not intended to be exhaustive, but to give you an idea of the support for Android devices. Your mileage may vary." (http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/features/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at m-gwt: http://www.m-gwt.com

This is a mobile library for GWT, that works very nicely.
It uses core GWT concepts (rebinding, clientbundles, ...).